# What are my rights if my boss paid me 600 euro too much for 2 years long?

Tags: contract-law, human-rights, payment, netherlands

My little brother, lets call him A for now, came to me today and said his boss, call him B, came to him and said that he (B) had been paying him (A) 600 euro too much for 2 years long. Ofcourse B wants the money back but he is not sure yet how and will come back to A after talking with the money manager (I guess accountant). A does not want to pay 14.400 euro at once, and getting paid 600 less each month for 2 years will bring him bankrupt (though we could probably figure some things out).

My question is: What are A his rights? Does he *have* to pay the money back? Must it be all at once? All the two years? And what happens if he leaves the company right now? Is he even able to?

**Some details about A and B and how this happened:**

A started working for B almost 3 years ago (he was 16). 2 years ago some software of B its company, that made sure payments happen automatically, stopped. But the payments did not (idk how exactly this happened or worked). The idea was that B pre-paid A (and all other employees) 150 each week. And substracted in week 4 the 600 (4 weeks * 150) from the monthly wage. Because B it's company stopped the software something went wrong and did not substract this 600 for 2 years. A is the only employee this happened to, A says. The company falls within the [Bouw & Infra CAO](https://www.fnv.nl/cao-sector/bouwen-wonen/bouw-infra/cao-bouw-infra).

**A works in the Netherlands, therefore I would like an answer about the rights in NL.**

**As reply to comment:**

I dont know how much A has been spending. Though he told me he could technically pay it. So he has 15k. To be clear btw, A never knew he got paid too much, he really didn't. He does not check those things.

A should have been receiving his normal month wage each month minus the 600. Because the 600 is already paid each week within the month (4 / 600 = 150 a week paid). What he got is his normal monthly wage + the 600. They never substracted it.

"loan"? Sorry bad translation on my part, corrected it. It means wage/wages.

**What happened on payslip:**
Normally what should happen is A his normal wage should be shown as pay-out but also -600 "pre-paid" should be shown. What actually was shown on the payslip was the normal wage without the -600 pre-paid. Making it look like a normal payslip.

**How A and B in the end handled the situation:**
A and B agreed to each pay 1/3 of the money. So A pays back 1/3 of the money. B pays 2/3 and the accountant of B pays 3/3. I don't know why exactly the accountant pays 3/3.

Comment: Related: [Getting paid by mistake after leaving a company?](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/82701/35069), but not an obvious duplicate.

Comment: Has A been spending the extra 600 a month? How much "should" A have been receiving each month? What's this about a "loan"?

Comment: @sharur I added my reply to my question.

Comment: Also related over on Expats, from 2016, is: [In the Netherlands, am I obligated to refund a previous employer for missing deductions?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/8999/20755). One comment has a broken link to what appears to be relevant caselaw so I've pinged the user to see if they could fix it.

Comment: @Rick [I think I found it](https://www.intermediair.nl/personal-finance/inkomen/mag-de-werkgever-teveel-betaald-loon-terugvorderen#:~:text=In%20principe%20kan%20de%20werkgever,loon%20van%20de%20werknemer%20terugvorderen.). Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @Rick This text within that page says alot I guess: `In principe kan de werkgever het teveel betaalde loon terugvorderen omdat het onverschuldigd is betaald. Maar als de werknemer aannemelijk kan maken dat hij volstrekt niet wist dat de loonbetaling niet klopte dat kan de werkgever in redelijkheid niet het teveel betaalde loon van de werknemer terugvorderen`. Sorry it's in dutch. I tried google translate but that messes up the whole message. It's an old document tho, 2014.

Comment: I just google translated and it seems to make a lot of sense, what is "messed up" about it? This is what I got: *In principle, the employer can reclaim the excess wages because they were paid unduly. But if the employee can demonstrate that he was completely unaware that the wage payment was incorrect, the employer cannot reasonably reclaim the excess wage from the employee.*

Comment: @Esther Oh hey, that indeed looks like the correct translation and the same I get now. Maybe my mind was not their at the time... :(

Comment: The accountant is responsible for the overpayment, that's most likely why they pay a part.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on the state of mind. If your brother's salary was €4,000 a month, but €4,600 was paid *and your brother believed that was the correct salary*, then he would have relied on that. He wouldn't have asked for a raise because he was happy with the salary. He wouldn't have left for another job paying €4,600 because he would have believed that isn't an improvement.

So if the company made your brother believe that the salary was €4,600 a month, they are very much at fault as well. They didn't just hand over the cash, your brother would also have received a payslip. And the payslip is an official document, that you would have used to calculate your taxes for example, that you need to be able to rely on. If I had to check what my salary is, the payslip would have been what I refer to.

It would be a different situation if the money he was owed according to the payslip and the money being paid into his bank account were different. It may be different if the payment suddenly went up for no reason.

If this is what his payslip says: He should tell the boss that he remembers quite clearly negotiating for the higher salary. And that he checked his first payslip, and if that payslip had been lower than he would have known that the company wants to pay less, and either negotiated some more, or left immediately. Paying him from month 1 means that they agreed to this payment. Asking him after 24 months is entirely unfair since he was under the impression that the salary would be higher, and that is why he didn't ask for a raise or leave the company.

Comment: Thats a good one actually. When im home I will ask him if the extra 600 also ended up on his payslip. Thanks for the help! I will come back to you.

Comment: @Allart Better to check the contract and see if it matches the payslip, then check what was actualy paid.

Comment: @MarkJohnson What is more likely: A company being so incompetent that they overpay for 24 months, or a company trying to rip off an employee?

Comment: @MarkJohnson But the salary on the contract is not up to date I belive. When they change it they do not send you a new contract.

Comment: @gnasher729 A judge will only be intersted in **facts**, not wild speculations. They will want to see the employment contract (plus any Addendum to the employment contract) ; the payslips to see if the agreed amount is being paid and the net amount (after taxes etc.) being paid out ; then the amounts actualy being transfered. Should the final result show that the double amount was actualy paid out, then the judge will come to the conclusion that overpaid amount should be returned. The judge will **not** agree with you that the 'company [is] trying to rip off an employee'.

Comment: @Allart An Addendum to the employment contract is often made, when the agreed amount is changed.

Comment: @MarkJohnson and gnasher729. Look at my edit. I added some info about this.

Comment: @Allart This voluntary settlement sounds very reasonable since both the employer and the accountant are also responsible for not having noticed the problem much earlier. It also keeps a greater portion of your brothers savings intact.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yeah I agree. They handled it well imo. No unnecessary conflict.

Comment: @MarkJohnson You seem to be very angry. Let's first state that it turned out you _were_ indeed wrong. You found one law, and assumed that's the whole story. It rarely is. And what is on someone's payslip isn't "wild speculation". It is facts. Payslip is a legally binding document.

Comment: Gnasher, personally I don't see him as angry at all, he is trying to help. He might have misunderstand things, like we all do here and there. Just keep in mind that you're very critical which can come of as harsh. Atleast thats what I get from reading your posts. You both seem to have moved in a defending state which also doesn't improve the "not getting angry" thing.

Comment: I'm not angry, but the statement/"wild speculation": 'company trying to rip off an employee' serves no purpose what so ever when it is clear that the employer paid out €14400 to much.

Answer (score 0):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

> Does he have to pay the money back?

Yes, based on §812 German Civil Code, since there was no legal ground for the extra € 600 per month.

> (1) A person who obtains something as a result of the performance of another person or otherwise at his expense **without legal grounds** for doing so is under a duty to make restitution to him. ...

Only when your brother didn't notice the extra sum when it was paid out **and** spent it (no longer enriched), would §818(3) come into effect.

> Though he told me he could technically pay it. So he has 15k.

Since the sum (24*600=14400) is available, it must be paid back.

The employer can require him to pay back the whole sum at once since it is available.

> And what happens if he leaves the company right now?

Your brother would still be liable for his debt.

> Is he even able to?

Yes.

---

**Sources**:

- [German Civil Code (Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch BGB)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/index.html)

  - [§812 - Claim for restitution](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p3473)
  - [§818 - Scope of the claim to enrichment](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p3476)

  > (3) The liability to undertake restitution or to reimburse the value is excluded to the extent that the recipient **is no longer enriched**.

  - [§819 - Increased liability in case of knowledge and breaches of law or public policy](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p3478)

  > (1) If the recipient, **at the time of receipt**, knows of the defect in the legal basis **or if he learns of it later**, then he is obliged to make restitution from the moment of receipt or of obtaining knowledge of the defect to make restitution as if the claim for restitution had been pending from this time on.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for your answer. I have a question though. Does Germany have the same law as the Netherlands? Since im looking for an answer about the Netherlands. Also, what do they mean with prestation? The employer made a mistake, not a prestation right?

Comment: @Allart Sorry, I compleatly overlooked the Netherlands tag. They may be similar, but I am not familiar with the dutch civil code. This is basicly about contract law. The employer made a mistake, but the employee now knows that he has been overpaid.

Comment: No problem ofcourse! I don't mind the answer. I still don't understand how knowing means someone has to pay it back. He only knows because the employee told him after 2 years he made a mistake. Isn't there a point where it is the employer its problem instead of the employee? What if the employer paid him too much for 1 year and the other 1 year the employee was already not working there anymore. Does he still have to pay? After such a long period?

Comment: @Allart There are 2 parties to the contract, both didn't check the monthly payments. Only when the employer knew throughout the period and undertook nothing  would the situation change.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: He doesn't know he was _overpaid_. He knows that what he thinks is the correct payment and what he relied on, and what the company thinks is the correct payment, are not the same.

Comment: @Allart It would be better to change the human-rights tag to contract-law.

Comment: @gnasher729 Once the employer called him and informed him of the fact, then he knew that he had been overpaid. Had the brother noticed it  beforhand and said nothing, then it could be considered fraud. Then there is the case (not meantioned) that in the first year the brother was a minor - but someone must of signed the contract for him.

Comment: Mark, the employer told him after two years. Anything before that the employee didn't know. And there is a major problem for the employer: The employee _believed_ that his salary was higher, and that is very much the fault of the employer. So making this change will make the employee want to quit and look for a place that actually pays €600 more. Plus who says this is a fact? It's the employer's opinion, two years later. My first job in the UK, my salary was £2,000 higher than the job offer. Two years later someone might find the job offer and want £4000 back, but that was not my salary.

Comment: @gnasher729 The contract states what is to be paid.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, first it turns out you were wrong. Second, the employer _knew_ what payments were made. The employer is a company. For a company, stupidity is no excuse. If a company makes four extra payments every month then they legally know, whether they are aware of it or not. There were payments going out, there was a bank account that got lower, they knew.

Comment: @gnasher729 Just as you answer contains generalized speculation, so does your comment. This is a matter of **contract law**, where both parties are **responsible** in insuring that the contract is upheld. So your statement: 'and your brother believed that was the correct salary, then he would have relied on that.' would be rejected by a judge (based on the from the OP quoted dutch law, which is the same in german law). You answer quotes no laws whatsoever. (Remember this is a **law** forum) ; 'then they legally know': please state the law where that is stipulated.